# Very basic java for android, why does program shut down when Button is pressed?

Tags: java, android, textview

Just started checking out android development, but having problems already. The activity shuts down when button bConvert is pressed. The outputValue.setText is apparently used wrong. Whats up? Thank you for help! :)

```
public class StartingPoint extends Activity {
    TextView outputValue;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        Button bConvert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bConvert);
        EditText inputValue = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etInput);
        TextView outputValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.userOutput);
        bConvert.setOnClickListener(convertHandler);
    }

    View.OnClickListener convertHandler = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            outputValue.setText("Fahrenheit: "+ 100);
        }
    };

    private float convert(float celsius) {
        return ((celsius*9/5)+32);
    }
}
```

Comment: What problems are you having? Be specific, paste error messages.

Comment: There isn't really a question in this title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `TextView outputValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.userOutput);` line with

```
outputValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.userOutput);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you initialize `outputValue`, you are creating a local variable instead of initializing your class variable.

Comment: No, it doesn't. The global variable, declared inside the class, can be accessed without the `final` "trick". I'll see if I can find the proper, canonical reference for it. ;-) The solution is indeed your first paragraph. I like your answer better because you took the time to explain.

Comment: @David that's why I said fairly certain, I was too lazy to actually make sure. :)

Comment: No prob... Sorry, I couldn't find the official reference. Anyway, as I said, the outer class member don't need to be `final` nor `static`, at least in that example. If you move the listener to inside a method, then I'm "fairly certain" :-) it will need to be `static` (not `final`), or else the compiler will throw the famous "cannot make a static reference to the non-static field..." That's the reason why I reuse global listeners like that (and you see lots of that in android code). A global `final` declaration in that case wouldn't work because of initialization issues, of course.